# Make a difference between Show and create routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have all those routes:

```
Route::resource('tournaments', 'TournamentController');
```

And in TournamentController, I have :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth')->except('show');
}
```

But When I go to http://laravel.dev/tournaments/create, Laravel thinks create is the tournament slug ( like http://laravel.dev/tournaments/my-tournament/ ) and send me to @show instead of @create.

In this case, I get a Model Not Found coming from SubstituteBindings Middleware...

I don't really understand this one, how can I avoid this confusion???

EDIT: Also list of my routes :

```
POST      | tournaments                                                                   | tournaments.store          | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@store                            | web,ownTournament,auth          |
GET|HEAD  | tournaments                                                                   | tournaments.index          | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@index                            | web,auth                        |
GET|HEAD  | tournaments/create                                                            | tournaments.create         | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@create                           | web,ownTournament,auth          |
GET|HEAD  | tournaments/deleted                                                           |                            | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@getDeleted                       | web,ownTournament,auth          |
GET|HEAD  | tournaments/{tournament}                                                      | tournaments.show           | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@show                             | web                             |
PUT|PATCH | tournaments/{tournament}                                                      | tournaments.update         | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@update                           | web,ownTournament,auth          |
DELETE    | tournaments/{tournament}                                                      | tournaments.destroy        | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@destroy                          | web,ownTournament,auth          |
GET|HEAD  | tournaments/{tournament}/edit                                                 | tournaments.edit           | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@edit                             | web,ownTournament,auth          |
```

EDIT: Now I have the same problem with another route:

```
Route::get('/tournaments/deleted', 'TournamentController@getDeleted');
```

I get a Model not found by SubstituteBindings Middleware.

I guess Middle is trying to resolve deleted as a tournament name...

Case re-opened!

Comment: Do you have the corresponding methods in `TournamentController` like (**create**, **show**, **edit**...)?

Comment: Yes I do! I have index, create, store, show, edit,  update, destroy, and 2 more

Comment: you don't need route names! laravel is naming them exactly as you did! try to remove them and test again

Comment: you don't need to specify all the name if you are define the route as a resource route. when you do `Route::resource('tournaments')`, you can access all of its methods as `tournaments.AnyMethodInController`.

Comment: I deleted all names, but problem still remains

Comment: I will suggest you make a new model and controller, and see if it persist. ill help you live here if you can do it now.

Comment: I have a lot of controllers that have create and show in the same controller, and none is failing....

Comment: That's exactly why i want you to make it fresh.

Comment: Ok. I will do a new one, give me 5 min

Comment: Maybe you should try visiting it via POST

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I had this route:

```
Route::get('tournaments/{tournament}', 'TournamentController@show')->name('tournaments.show');
```

at the beginning of my route file.

My bad! I let the answer here for people who get the same problem!